# Equivalence of two processes or implication that one is better than the other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, quality-control, equivalence

**The problem**

Two different tools $M1$ and $M2$ are supposed to deliver a certain amount of volume of a liquid but in different ways. Furthermore, the efficacity of the tools to deliver this volume decreases (slightly) with the time. We want to show that the process M2 is better than or equivalent to the process M1. There is a minimum amount of volume that each tool should deliver with a probability of at least $0.9999$, let us note it $V_m$.

**The data**

The data for the process $M2$ are only summarized data: the means and standard deviations of $n$ data are available at each time points for a finite number of time points $T = 6$.

The data for process $M1$ are individuals values and we have $n$ individual values at each time points.

**What I did**
I used equivalence testing on the means in a first step. Because we only have summary data for one process, I aimed to show that:
$$
|\mu_1(t) - \mu_2(t)| < \delta    \ \ \ (C1)
$$
with a one two-sided t-test, where $\mu_1(t)$ respectively $\mu_2(t)$ is the mean of the process $M1$ respectively $M2$ at the time point $t$. The I used tolerance interval to fix a criteria on the standard deviation as follows:

$$
\mu_2 - \delta - k \lambda\sigma_2 > V_m, \ \ \ \ (C2)
$$
where $k$ is the k-factor related to tolerance interval based on normal distribution, $\sigma_2$ is the standard deviation of $M2$ at a given time point and $\lambda$ is a multiplicator factor that I will explain now.

In the equation above, $\mu_2 - \delta$ is the worst value that $M1$ can take  if condition $(C1)$ is fulfilled (i.e., the closest to the lower limit $V_m$) and then $\lambda\sigma_2$ is the largest possible value for $\sigma_1$ to still fulfill condition $(C2)$.$\lambda$ is easy to find. Then you just test for the ratio of standard deviations being bigger than $\lambda$:

$$
\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2} < \lambda \ \ \ (C3).
$$

However, i was not able to demonstrate $(C3)$ for all time points so there is a method to increase $\lambda$ by testing $(C1')$ instead of $(C1)$:
$$
\mu_1(t) - \mu_2(t) > \delta    \ \ \ (C1')
$$
and so $(C2)$ can become $(C2')$:
$$
\mu_2 - k \lambda\sigma_2 > V_m, \ \ \ \ (C2').
$$

**remark**
Some power studies should be carried out before doing the equivalence testing in $(C2),(C2')$ that will give a $\delta' < \delta$.

**Question**

The framework proposed looks a bit complicated and I am looking for something maybe less complex. Do you have any criticism on the method proposed (it is always really interesting to discuss) and any alternatives ?

I thought about linear regression but I do not really think that is a strong enough method to show $M2$ performs as good as or better than $M1$.